# Storing a mailing list in Database / MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with millions of records (rows).
And in this table there is a column in the table called mail_to.
Corresponding to each record there is a mailing list and then information of mailing list is stored in this column mail_to.
In the current implementation of my system, I have stored the mailing list as a list of comma separated mail ids.

For example 
Consider a table, **Subscription Data**

```
     | Column A | Column B |........ | mail_to                     |
     | Record 1 | abc      |         | xyz@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com |
```

The current implementation  works fine if I want to retrieve mailing list corresponding to a record. But if I want to search the records corresponding to abc@gmail.com,  querying  is too slow.

One way I could think was

Storing Column A to Column N in **Subscription Data** 
and then mail ids in a separate table say **User Email Data** 
and a third table that stores the information of join.

But, I am not sure if it will give me any improvement since there will be 2 joins every time I will query.

Can any one suggest a better way to store this mailing list/ help me evaluate which is better of the two. Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store both variants, although it violates 3NF. But if you looking for speed - some denormalization may help.

You may use the old concatenated list of mails for some your processing and use your new multitable schema for fast search.

Answer (score 0):

First off

- Databases are designed to JOIN.
- Databases aren't designed to scan CSV data to extract a partial string.

Your current design break the first rule of normalisation: no repeating groups.

As you noted, you should have something like this (UQ = unique)

**Subscription**

- SubscriptionDataID (PK)
- ColumnB
- ColumnC
- ...

**UserEmail**

- EmailDetailID (PK)
- SubscriptionDataID (FK)
- EmailAddress (UQ)

Comment: Hi gbn, Thanks for the comment but the reason I suggested 3 tables was because a user can have multiple subscriptions. I am not sure how I can do that with the your suggested schema.

Comment: I agree that I did not mention it explicitly but the statement  " But if I want to search the records corresponding to abc@gmail.com, querying is too slow." specifies that there can be multiple records that belong to the same user.